# How to put GXT Grid values to Map

Tags: gwt, grid, gwt2, gxt

I want to save the grid header and col data in HashMap.

```
Map<String,List<String>> gridData = new HashMap<String,List<String>>(); // key ->header , value -> list of col



    ColumnModel<RiaBean> columnModel = grid.getColumnModel();
    for (int colonne = 0; colonne < columnModel.getColumnCount(); colonne++) {
        String header= columnModel.getColumnHeader(colonne).toString();

    /* missing code 
        **i have header name how to get the list of values of that header**
    */

    gridData.put(header,list<>)
```

i missing code part i want get list of all values of same header

Please help.

Comment: Are you working with GXT 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to assign id to all column as follow

```
ColumnConfig xyz = new ColumnConfig();
xyz.setId("xyz");
xyz.setHeader("xyz");

ColumnConfig abc = new ColumnConfig();
abc.setId("abc");
abc.setHeader("abc");
```

than after you have to fetch all record from grid using following code

```
Map<String,List<String>> gridData = new HashMap<String,List<String>>(); 

List<String> xyzList = new ArrayList();
List<String> abcList = new ArrayList();

for (ColumnConfig column : grid.getColumnModel().getColumns()) {
   for (DatastoreConfig datastoreConfig : grid.getStore().getModels()) {
         if(column.getId().equals("xyz")){
               xyzList.add(datastoreConfig.get(column.getId()).toString());
         }

         if(column.getId().equals("abc")){
               abcList.add(datastoreConfig.get(column.getId()).toString());
         }
     }
 }

gridData.put("xyz",xyzList);
gridData.put("abc",abcList);
```

hope it will help you.